# Any good write up for Dual simplex with boxed variables?

Tags: simplex, dual-simplex

I was wondering if there is any write up that shows how to perform dual simplex with boxed variables where `l <= x <= u` and preferably with a small example (like 4-5 variable problem with a few iterations).

I tried searching but I keep getting into some dissertations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pan's book chapter 8: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-19-0147-8 . It has examples.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity, you can write the bounded variable as two additional constraints. In the following example, there are four positive variables with a bounded variable $3 \leq x_1 \leq 5$.

\begin{array}{l}
\text{Maximize} & Z =  -15x_1 - 10x_2 - 8x_3 - 4x_4\\
\text{subject to:}& \\
&-3x_1 - 5x_2 - 3x_3 \leq -5\\
&-5x_1 - 2x_2 - 6x_4 \leq -3\\
&x_1 \geq  3\\
&x_1 \leq  5\\
&x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \geq 0,
\end{array}

Now, by performing the dual simplex algorithm the problem is solved in four iterations.

[image]

To try that yourself please, took a look at this [link](https://cbom.atozmath.com/CBOM/Simplex.aspx?q=ds&q1=4%604%60MAX%60Z%60x1%2cx2%2cx3%2cx4%60-15%2c-10%2c-8%2c-4%60-3%2c-5%2c-3%2c0%3b-5%2c-2%2c0%2c-6%3b1%2c0%2c0%2c0%3b1%2c0%2c0%2c0%60%3c%3d%2c%3c%3d%2c%3e%3d%2c%3c%3d%60-5%2c-3%2c3%2c5%60%60D%60false%60true%60false%60true%60false%60false%60true%601&dp=2&do=1#PrevPart).

Answer (score 2):

Two good options:

- [István Maros: Computational Techniques of the Simplex Method](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4615-0257-9)
- [Achim Koberstein: The dual simplex method, techniques for a fast and stable implementation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Achim-Koberstein/publication/35632487_The_dual_simplex_method_techniques_for_a_fast_and_stable_implementation_Elektronische_Ressource/links/0a85e52ef5144e9031000000/The-dual-simplex-method-techniques-for-a-fast-and-stable-implementation-Elektronische-Ressource.pdf)

The second one is a dissertation but I don't understand why this should be an issue.

Comment: Thanks! I was just hoping for something with simple ratio tests and a bit self contained. Like maybe a 4-5 pages of write up with a few small examples.

Answer (score 2):

A textbook that deals with this at the undergraduate level is Chvatal's *Linear Programming*.   Sadly, it's out of print, but you might be able to find it in an academic library.